# Почему сначала идёт квадратная скобка, а потом запятая?

Tags: php

> string trim ( string $str [, string $character_mask = " \t\n\r\0\x0B" ] )

Почему квадратные скобки? для визуализации?
Почему сначала идет квадратная скобка, а потом запятая. Но не наоборот?

Comment: обычно таким образом (в скобках) обозначаются необязательные параметры

Answer (score 0):

В скобках, обозначают необязательные параметры, сами по себе они не всегда требуют скобки, не стоит воспринимать скобки как массив, для обозначения массива, напишут явный тип, а скобки используют именно чтобы пометить необязательный параметр, по сколько запятая после обязательного параметра по сути является частью необязательного параметра, запятую тоже помещают в скобки.